# Is it possible to boot the same ubuntu sometimes as a virtual machine, and sometimes on the physical pc?

Tags: boot, windows, virtualbox, vmware

Is it at all possible to have the same ubuntu with the same updates and installed apps, sometimes boot in a vmware/vbox/or-similar inside windows, and sometimes be able to boot it on the startup of the computer ?

Without having to migrate from one place to another each time.

Answer (score 1):

[Please note that I have never booted an OS off a phyiscal drive using a vm but it can be done.]

You can assign a vm to use a hard drive partition directly rather than a .vdi, .vhd, or .vdmk file. You can do this under the VM settings in Vmware player by adding a generic scsi device and choosing the partition you want. Please note that the vm only has access to that partition which presents a few problems:

1. On BIOS computers the bootloader is stored on the hard drives mbr and therefore will not be available to the vm making the OS unbootable. You will need to create a virtual hard drive that has a bootloader setup to boot an os from the scsi device. On UEFI systems a similar problem will occur.
2. The swap parition won't be available, I'm not familiar enough with swap to suggest a work-around for this. Missing swap won't prevent booting, but you should get an error message at least the first time, and it will affect performance of the VM if you don't have a swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

intresting idea! I have never tried, but [this](http://merx3.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/booting-an-existing-ubuntu-instalation-from-virtualbox-while-using-windows/) blog claims to explain how to do it if I am correct.